# qsort not sorting structure correctly

Tags: c, struct, qsort

I'm trying to sort a structure I've created via qSort however it seems to be be doing what I expect it to.

This is my compare function

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const INPUT *p1 = a;
    const INPUT *p2 = b;
    return ((p1->startTime) - (p2->startTime));
}
```

Where INPUT is my structure and startTime is an int within it.

I call qsort by this

```
qsort(*global,fileNumber,sizeof(global)/fileNumber,compare);
```

Where global is the variable name of INPUT, fileNumber is how many entries are within the global variable.

From the printf statements I've written it seems to do nothing.

I've initialized at the beginning of my code global like this

```
INPUT *global[4];
```

Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What're the definitions of `fileNumber` and `global`? Not sure, but it looks like `global` is a pointer, so `sizeof(global)` may not be what you are after, and you probably don't want to dereference it in the first parameter either.

Comment: Do you mean *global in the qsort line? Or just global? What's the type of "global"?

Comment: Taking the difference like that as the return value of your comparison function is almost always wrong. It's vulnerable to numeric overflow errors.

Answer (score 2):

As you send `*global` to `qsort`, I can imagine that you defined `global` as:

```
INPUT **global;
```

Thus, when you give `sizeof(global)/fileNumber` as third argument to `qsort`, `sizeof` is probably 4 (or 8 on a 64 bits systems). Then this argument is propably zero.

Hence `qsort` does nothing on a zero element array, and never calls `compare`.

Answer (score 1):

You `global` array is an array of pointers, not an array of INPUT structs.  So your compare function should look something like:

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const INPUT **p1 = a;
    const INPUT **p2 = b;
    return (((*p1)->startTime) - ((*p2)->startTime));
}
```

And your call to `qsort()`:

```
qsort(global,fileNumber,sizeof(global)/fileNumber,compare);
```

Of course, all this assumes that you are really using `global` as an array of pointers rather than a pointer to an array of INPUT structs.